# Makefile - No rule to make target `PATH/TO/file.o`

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm really new to makefile and I'm struggling to make it compile all the .cpp files inside the src folder.

right now the makefile looks like this:

```makefile
SRC_DIR = src
OBJ_DIR = build/obj
INCLUDE_DIR = $(SRC_DIR)/inc

SRC_DIRS = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR) $(SRC_DIR)/* $(INCLUDE_DIR)/*)
C_FILES = $(filter %.cpp, $(wildcard $(SRC_DIRS)/*.cpp))
OBJ_FILES = $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/, $(notdir $(C_FILES:.cpp=.o)))

INCLUDE_PATH = -I$(INCLUDE_DIR)
CXXFLAGS = $(INCLUDE_PATH)
CXX = g++
CFLAGS = -Wall -g
CC = gcc

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIRS)/%.cpp

pile: $(OBJ_FILES)

test:
        @echo $(C_FILES)
        @echo $(OBJ_FILES)
```

and what I want to achieve with each rule is:

- `pile:` when calling `make pile` it should check for all the .o files inside `build/obj`.
- `$(OBJ_DIR)/%.cpp:` find the equivalent `.cpp` file inside the source folder and compile it.

I suppose that there's something wrong with my second rule, but I can't really tell why cause the `test` rule is printing all the files.. :/

thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: It's strongly recommend to use `CMake` instead, and a `Makefile` should not be used if your project has more than one target (or is complex, with many dependency).

Comment: thanks, but it's a project with learning purposes and one of the things that I want to learn is makefile xD. It shouldn't be a large project, though, I just don't want to add a new rule for each file.

Comment: Anything that has 1 or more dependency, will cause you a lot of head-ache (if you was not asked to take-over an existing `Makefile` project, don't bother learning, you miss nothing ;-))

Comment: well, I'll take a look at `CMake` and see if it makes it any easier. thank you :)

Comment: Recommending cmake is personal opinion, does not answer the question. There are many legitimate uses for make.

Comment: CMake is a fine tool, but it has its own quirks and complexity.  CMake does some things automatically for you which are very useful, but some things that are trivial to do with make are very difficult to do with CMake.  CMake is particularly good if your project needs to run on different platforms with different IDEs.  But it's not really appropriate to suggest "use CMake" unless there's something about the question that CMake is specifically suited for.  Else it's like going to a random question on C and saying "you should just use Python".  Not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like SRC_DIRS could be an array which will not be happy with that matcher function.
Try changing:

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIRS)/%.cpp
```

to

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
```

Comment: that didn't work :/ and also the cpp file may (and probably will) be in a subfolder, if I use the $(SRC_DIR) alone it wouldn't work, right?

Comment: Yes, the matcher is looking to build an object within OBJ_DIR, whos name matchs a CPP file that exists within SRC_DIR. 
If make cannot find that matching cpp file, the rule is non-applicable and thus it will keep looking, ultimately ending in "cannot find rule"

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems here but the most fundamental is that you are not actually defining a rule when you write this line:

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIRS)/%.cpp
```

A rule consists of targets, prerequisites and *a recipe*.  Here you have not provided a recipe, so you haven't told make how to actually build anything.

The other issue is as mentioned by @Ryan-Miller; you can't use multiple directories in a single rule like this.  But you can just avoid the complexity anyway if all your source files are in a single directory.

If that's not what you want please make your question clear as to ALL the different things you need.  You wrote "*$(OBJ_DIR)/%.cpp: find the equivalente .cpp file inside the source folder and compiles it*".  How exactly are you defining "the equivalent .cpp file"?  Computer programming is all about the details!

Comment: I haven't added a recipe because I was trying to use the implicit rules as mentioned [here](https://makefiletutorial.com). And yes, as you mentioned, the _find the equivalent .cpp_  is not very clear to me, I'm mapping all the cpp files to their equivalent .o when I define the `OBJ_FILES`, but I can't tell for sure how I could do the other way around.. so consider it part of the question, I guess.

Comment: An implicit rule, such as a pattern rule, requires you to create a recipe for it as I say in my answer.  You can't just create a pattern target and prerequisites without a recipe: that's not a rule.  This line does nothing (technically it _cancels_ that pattern rule but since it doesn't exist, it doesn't actually do anything).

Comment: Before you can write a makefile, just like before you can write a program, requires you to know with specificity what you want the makefile to do.  If you can describe in words what the makefile should do, it's not hard, usually, to get it to do that.  Just like with a program, if you don't know what you want it to do it's not going to turn out so well.